# How to sort by most watched in X days/months

Tags: wp-query, loop

So I managed to loop my posts in a page template, ordering the posts by most viewed.

The query posts string looks like this

```
$wplover_home = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=18&v_sortby=views&v_orderby=desc&paged=' . $paged);

while ($wplover_home->have_posts()) : $wplover_home->the_post(); ?>
```

Now to my question. If I wanted to sort the posts by most viewed in X days or months, how should the string look like then? The documentation for the plugin (wp-postviews) doesn't have anything on this.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you mean by "x days or months", but I'm assuming you want to set a time interval for the posts that you are querying. I would recommend that you take a look at the ["Time Parameters" section in the Codex article on WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters). It does an excellent job explain how to limit the query by day, month, year, or for a specific interval. If you have a question after reviewing that, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks for that. But adding day=7 to the query string just shows posts from the last 7 days - not the most watched posts in the last 7 days :-) As started below, it is not possible. What a shame :(

Comment: Oh...yep...that would be a big problem. Have you looked into using JetPack which provides you with WordPress.com stats and a handy API for getting such information?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to sort by only the views in the past XX days. It is not possible, as the plugin does not record the date. More information [here](http://forums.lesterchan.net/index.php/topic,2393.0.html).

Comment: Oh no, thats bad. Do you know of any alternative method to do so?

Comment: Try http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/recent-post-views/. You will have to look into the source for the query, though.